# Pandas dataframe - create multiple columns based on multiple conditions calculations

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, data.table

I am learning python so please excuse me if my question is too basic. Actually I need to create multiple columns on my pandas dataframe based on different conditions. I can do this in R using data.table. I am pasting below my code with sample data from R-

```
library(data.table)

cr=4
phi=1.85

colA <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)
colB <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)
colC  <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)
SALES <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)
colD <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)
VALUE <- sample(1.05:20.00,1000,replace=T)

df <- as.data.table(data.frame(colA,colB,colC,colD,SALES,VALUE))

df <- df[, c("colB_exp","colC_exp", "Unit_exp","Value_exp") 
         := list (ifelse(!is.na(colA),pmin(colB *  colA,(cr-1)*1/phi^2+cr*SALES * colA),0),
                  ifelse(!is.na(colA),pmin(colC * colA,(cr-1)*1/phi^2+cr*SALES * colD * colA),0),      
                  ifelse(!is.na(colA),SALES * colA,0),
                  ifelse(!is.na(colA),VALUE * colA,0)
         )]
```

So as you see I need to create 4 columns in this example (actually there are 7 more columns with different conditions that needs to be created but for example purpose I am considering only 4)

Now I am trying to do the same in Python but not able to get how this can be done. Also I am not sure if I am doing it in a efficient manner as it seems too much of coding for each new column to be created.
Below is my sample data and code that I am trying in Python -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,100,size=(100, 6)), columns=list(['colA','colB','colC','colD','SALES','VALUE']))

cr=4
phi=1.85

def colB_exp(row):
    return min(df['colB'] *  df['colA'],(cr-1)*1/phi^2+cr* df['SALES'] * df['colA'])


df['colB_exp'] = df.apply(lambda row:colB_exp(row) if df['colA'].notnull().all() else 0,axis = 1)
```

But I am getting error as **TypeError: Cannot perform 'rxor' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]**

When I check data type of my df, all columns are float64 which is actually the case in my main data.

Not sure what the issue is how can I correct this.

And will I have to create functions for every column condition? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you !!

Comment: Exponent operator is `**` as opposed to `^`. And `min` will not work like this. Use `concat` than `.min(1)`

Comment: @SayandipDutta, Thank you for letting me know. I understand for the exponent to use `**` but not clear on the `min` part...why we need to `cancat`

Comment: You see `builtin min` does not work with `df`s. You will get `ValueError: Truth value of series is ambiguous ...`. You want element wise comparison for the right? If no, and you want to compare the values within the row itself, which you should, given you are planning to use apply, you should use `row['colB']` instead of `df['colB']` inside the function.

Comment: @SayandipDutta, Thank you very much for your explanation. also on changing `df` to `row` I am getting the results. Is this the way I need to create all columns....I mean for every new column I need to create a function and then use it....?

Comment: You can check out [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) so that you can create all at once. However, it seems like you do not need `apply`, for example, to create your column `'colB_exp'`, you can directly do:

 `df['colB_exp'] = np.where(df['colA'].notnull(), pd.concat([df['colB'] *  df['colA'],(cr-1)*1/phi**2+cr* df['SALES'] * df['colA']],axis=1).min(1), 0)` and so on...

Comment: @SayandipDutta, Thank you for this code. This is shorter and does without a function. I get now what you meant by `concat` and `min(1)`. If you could add this as answer I shall accept it. Thank you once again !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be faster if you avoid `apply`, you can do this using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,100,size=(100, 6)), 
                      columns=list(['colA','colB','colC','colD','SALES','VALUE']))

>>> cr=4
>>> phi=1.85
>>> df['colB_exp'] = np.where(
                              df['colA'].notnull(), 
                              pd.concat([
                                  df['colB'] *  df['colA'],
                                  (cr-1)*1/phi**2+cr* df['SALES'] * df['colA']
                                 ],axis=1).min(1), 0
                        )
>>> df

         colA       colB       colC  ...      SALES      VALUE     colB_exp
0   22.549300  64.278204  31.008298  ...  42.493048  59.603801  1449.428473
1   69.699479  69.173731  98.060696  ...  45.343364  40.046332  4821.373010
2   49.174025  81.000527  62.022084  ...  49.619752  18.370626  3983.121926
3   88.094696  33.193363  59.168448  ...  72.243254   8.378294  2924.159181
4   57.385150  14.326797  92.865076  ...  33.228036  55.651635   822.145427
..        ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...          ...
95  94.641142  39.684918  59.073406  ...  66.350751  38.040689  3755.825953
96   7.527524  10.376946  56.894015  ...   8.575608  71.710560    78.112711
97  12.258327  17.919200  97.053017  ...  22.476308  79.233166   219.659423
98  76.264761  60.973407  97.328900  ...  57.116251  29.756769  4650.122372
99  30.687590  77.486464   7.277809  ...  97.560641   4.835084  2377.872852

[100 rows x 7 columns]
```

You can look further into [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add multiple columns at once.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use min to directly compare 2 columns. It needs to be applied at the element level.
Can you please check if this breakdown does the job..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,100,size=(100, 6)), columns=list(['colA','colB','colC','colD','SALES','VALUE']))

cr = 4
phi = 1.85

def colB_exp():
    A = df['colB']* df['colA']
    B = (cr-1)*1/phi**2+cr* df['SALES'] * df['colA']
    return [min(a,b) for a,b in zip(A, B)]

df['colB_exp'] = colB_exp()
df['colB_exp'][df['colA'].isna()] = 0
df
```

Comment: thank you for your answer....I tried it on the data but the calculation for A does not seem to happen correctly from 2nd row onwards....Not sure why....

Comment: Sure.. can you give me some more details on it, about what's going wrong, and the expected result etc..

Comment: if you check the calculations for new column `colB_exp`, based on this code the calculation is not happening right for most of the rows....

Comment: Ah.. made a mistake with the formula used to compute B in the ```colB_exp``` function.. corrected that... in any case @Sayandip has posted a better solution.